# shadowing static variable ( global variable)

Tags: java, static, shadow

Why in the next code I get pro.x=11?. it should be 22. Please somebody throws a light.

```
public class Pro {
    static int x=11;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

    Pro pro=new Pro();
    pro.call(5);
    System.out.println(Pro.x);
    System.out.println(pro.x);  
    }
    public void call(int x){
        x=22;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are not modifying `Pro.x`, you are modifying the `int x` argument, which is discarded at the end of the method. Change to `Pro.x = 22` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

you are not setting the static/global variable to 22, but rather the value of the argument passed. Considering it's a primitive value, call by value is used and not call by reference.

Edit: In fact as pointed out in comments, java doesn't have have call by reference, but rather call by value of a reference.

If you just wisht to change the global variable, no argument is necessary for your function, you can do it this way:

```
public class Pro {
    static int x=11;

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

    Pro pro=new Pro();
    pro.call();
    System.out.println(Pro.x);
    System.out.println(pro.x);  
    }
    public void call(){
        Pro.x=22;   
    }
}
```

Comment: *Considering it's a primitive value, call by value is used and not call by reference.* - Everything is pass by value in java, not just primitives. The same code wouldn't work even with `x` being an `Object`.

Comment: Primitive is a call by value, objects call by value of a reference. Therefor you are correct for Java. However it seems to me that the OP expected a call by reference behavior as in C/C++, so I was referring to that.

Comment: Calling an object by the value of its reference is extremely confusing, especially for beginners, since the behavior is often times more similar to "call by reference" than to what java does with primitive types. We get this issue here a lot, dont we?

Comment: @hamenaglar I see your point, but it's still incorrect. Java passes **everything** by value, period. Primitive variables are passed by value, object references are passed by value. There is no pass-by-reference in java.

Comment: Also, the pass-by-value statement doesn't really make sense here. It seems to me that the OP is confused on why `x=22` is not modifying the static variable, and the reason is that `x` refers to the parameter instead of referring to the static variable. No explaination on the pass-by-value/reference is needed here, as it adds nothing useful to the answer and tends to confuse beginners.

Comment: @BackSlash, Considering he is passing x as a parameter in function, I would disagree. If he has some experience in C/C++ and has incorrectly heard that java uses calls by reference, which happens a lot.

Comment: @hamenaglar Again, this question is not about "call by reference". It is about why `x=22` doesn't update the static variable. It has nothing to do with passing by value or reference. It's called *shadowing*, as the OP already tagged. And again, it has nothing to do with how java passes arguments. We are talking about java here, not C. C/C++ are never mentioned in the question.

Comment: If he were wanting to just change the global variable, he wouldn't be passing the argument...

Comment: @hamenaglar - he wouldn't have tagged *shadowing*, which is the term that describes a local variable having the same name of a global variable, thus having precedence over it. Please, stick to what is asked, otherwise the OP can easily get confused, especially if he is a beginner.